# What happens if NullPointerException is not handled in main() method?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

In the below sample code snippet, NullPointerException is not being handled in the main() method after being implicitly propagated from check() method to main() method.

```
class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check(26);
    }

    public static void check(int a) throws SQLException, IOException {
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            throw new NullPointerException("it is divisible by 2"); //we are raising a Null pointer exception here
        } else if (a % 3 == 0) {
            throw new IOException("it is divisible by 3"); //we are raising a IO Exception here
        } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("it is divisible by 5"); //we are raising a SQL Exception here
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation error occurs at `check(26);` line of code throwing SQL Exception, IO Exception which are checked exceptions explicitly propagated from `check(int a)` method to main() method. If the NullPointerException is not handled in the main() method then where is it getting handled?

Comment: You never "handle" NPE's -- rather you debug your code to *prevent* them

Comment: Does that code compile? Your main method does not throw an exception nor does it have a try/catch

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am unable to compile the code as I see compile error at check(26) step in the code. Once you add try catch at that step, then I don’t see any compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought Hovercraft Full Of Eels is right that handling NPE usually is bad practice. You can handle it as well as any other unchecked exception.

```
try {
    // your code
    check(26);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // do something
}
```

You can read about unchecked exceptions here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 2):

> As we already know the Null pointer Exception is propagated implicitly without using throws keyword to main method

Not necessarily. If unhandled, it will propagate up the call tree to whatever the entry point was. If you're running code via the `java` tool (or something else that calls `main`), that will be `main`, but if you're using Swing, or writing a servlet, etc., it may well be a different entry point (it certainly will, with a servlet).

> but is it necessary if it should be handled in the main method.

It depends on what you mean by "necessary." If you don't, and you've run your code with the `java` tool, your program will terminate if there's an unhandled NPE.

Common practice is to not catch `NullPointerException`, because your code should never throw an NPE, so if it does, it's a bug that you want to fix (by finding out why the NPE was thrown and fixing that), rather than by catching the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception will be thrown at run time even we handle it it will be propagated
This exception talks about data

Answer (score 0):

First : note that in your actual code you don't throw relevant exceptions.
All these error cases should throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

`NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` not designed to be **specifically** caught by the client  (as many of JDK `RuntimeException` such as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, `ArithmeticException`, .... ).
As this is thrown, it generally means that the actual code that provoked that has an issue.
But should we catch it ?
In fact it depends on the point of the view of the class/component that has to cope with.

1) If from the point of view of the component/class that throws the `NullPointerException` we consider that it is a programming error that should be corrected by the developer,  we want that it be propagated until the client of the class.
So we don't want to catch it.

2) In other cases, we know that the `NullPointerException` is a programming error but we don't want that it stops the program and be propagated to the application user.  So we want to catch `NullPointerException` but also any exception that could cause an abnormal program termination.
So we enclose the "risky" code in a `catch(Exception)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has several issues and it would not compile because:

1. Your are calling a **non-static** method(check) from an **static** context(main).
2. You have not handled the **IOException, SQLException** exceptions in your main method(throw them or surround them with try catch)

   This is not related to **NPE(Null pointer exception)**, and as it is stated by others Null Pointer Exception is allowed by compilers because it is unchecked exception.

Comment: The code got compiled after making the changes mentioned by you. 1. Made the method static so that it can be accessed in main method 2. Added throws to the main method so that it propagates to the jvm

Comment: @Aditya Remember to vote up useful answers in order to encourage community members to help more.

Comment: Yeah sure and thanks for the inputs. I am doing the same